# Can I set bufferLength other than a power of two in AudioKit?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession, audiokit

In the `AKSettings` class of `AudioKit`, the `BufferLength` enum will only allows to set the buffer length to power of twos. Is this a limitation set by `AudioKit`, or this a limitation from the underlying `AVAudioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration()` that will force a power of two for the buffer length?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

My answer is that AudioKit is doing the enforcing because I've always seen buffer lengths as powers of two, but now that you ask I'm not exactly sure why that is. Perhaps AudioKit should encourage the buffer length to be powers of two but not enforce it strictly.

Comment: I could be very interested in this restriction being gone. That'd make it the same behavior as AAudio/Oboe on Android.

Comment: Take note of what the great Michael Tyson said here where he didn't want to change it from powers of 2 in TAAE:
https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine2/issues/67

Comment: But, I don't think we came up with the names of those buffer lengths ourselves. Pretty sure Apple used those at some point, so perhaps they lifted the restriction and so should we. I'll look into it. In the meantime you could fork AudioKit with your own custom AKSettings class that does allow this.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! I'll try using a custom AKSettings for now.